# Complex sentences, confusing pronouns

Tags: pronouns, phrase-analysis

To a ESL student like me, below sentence is very difficult to understand. I've read this sentence like 20 times and I still don't get it 100%.

> "Investors in the past have expressed to us that they do not understand why Tesla shares are rising as much as they are as the stock became included in the indices against which they are benchmarked, they opted anyhow to take it equal weight in their portfolio relative to their benchmark, so as to concentrate on generating alpha in other areas of the market in which they felt they have more of an edge," he added. ( [Original article link](https://www.thestreet.com/investing/tesla-trading-at-650-gets-90-price-target-from-jp-morgan) )

I can get the general sense from the quote.

1. Investors don't understand why Tesla stocks are rising.
2. They somehow adjusted weight in their investment portfolio to earn more profits.

But I'm confused about the details. I'm really not sure about these.

- Did the investors feel TESLA didn't have an edge against other portfolio items?
- So they see the rising stock price of the car company, change their mind, and decide to take the electric car maker equal weight in their portfolio? say increase TELSA 10% to 25% like the other 25% items?
- Or did the investors think they missed the opportunity and start concentrating other sectors in their portfolio??

And what bothers me a lot is the confusing pronouns ( to me ). Are these replacements correct?

> "Investors in the past have expressed to us that **(1. they)** do not understand why Tesla shares are rising as much as **(2. they)** are as the stock became included in the indices against which **(3. they)** are benchmarked, **(4. they)** opted anyhow to take **(5. it)** equal weight in their portfolio relative to (6. their) benchmark, so as to concentrate on generating alpha in other areas of the market in which **(7. they)** felt **(8. they)** have more of an edge," he added.

> "Investors in the past have expressed to us that **(1. Investors)** do not understand why Tesla shares are rising as much as **(2. Tesla shares)** are as the stock became included in the indices against which **(3. Telsa shares)** are benchmarked, **(4. Investors)** opted anyhow to take **(5. the stock)** equal weight in their portfolio relative to **(6. Tesla shares)** benchmark, so as to concentrate on generating alpha in other areas of the market in which **(7. Investors)** felt **(8. other areas of the market)** have more of an edge," he added.

It'd be grateful if somebody could rephrase this sentence with easy sentence structure for ESL learners.

Comment: It's pretty convoluted, which is appropriate since it describes some people's confused beliefs about other people's confused beliefs about uncertain investments, and is entirely speculative in its conclusions. If you thought you did understand it, you should be dubious.